# Get unique values from database column (each cell has comma separated value)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get unique values as list option from database column through foreach where each cell has multiple values seperated by comma.

Database cell:

1. Door, Window
2. Window, Sheet
3. Sheet, Door

I'm trying to get the following as the select option:

1. Door
2. Window
3. Sheet

I'm using laravel and and tryied the follwing:

My controller looks like:

```
$products = DB::table('dealers')->select('products')->distinct()->get();
```

My blade view looks like:

```
<select>
<option value="">All</option>
@foreach( $products as $product)
    <?php
    foreach(explode(", ", $product->products) as $value)

        printf(
            '<option value="%1$s">
                                    %1$s
                                </option>',
            $value
        );
    ?>
@endforeach
```

I'm getting the following output as:
[1] Door [2] Window [3] Window [4] Sheet [5] Sheet [6] Door

Can anyone please help! I need to make it: [1] Door [2] Window [3] Sheet

Comment: This is a design problem. The products should be distinct entities in a related table, not delimited lists.

Comment: [Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-unique-values-from-database-column-each-cell-has-comma-separated-value) is what worked for me!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

PHP has a large standard library of array functions, including [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique)

### EDIT

I missed the outer loop. You have to get unique-ness for the whole data set, not just per-row

```
$uniqueProducts = array_unique(array_merge(...array_map(function($row) {
   return explode(', ', trim($row));
}, $products));
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple you can save each term in array. then check if not value exists in array.
Try laravel blade view code below:

```
<select>
    <option value="">All</option>
    <?php $array = []; ?>
    @foreach( $products as $product)
        @foreach(explode(", ", $product->products) as $value)
            @if(!in_array($value, $array))
            <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $value }}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```